# force compiler to reveal type of a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, compiler-errors

I am compiling a rather large project in which I faced with

> error: ‘CRoom room’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

Right at

```
class CRoom
{
.....
} room("test");
```

The problem is that I searched into the whole my project files and I could not find such a variable anywhere else. Is it possible to force the complier to tell me where it has found the original place of such definition? If it is not possible, at least, is it possible to reveal the type of the original variable at comfile time (Note that this programs has so many other errors and I cannot run it and show variable type. I want the compiler reveals the type for me).

Comment: The other `room` needn't be a variable, it could also be a `typedef` or a function. The error message should tell you where the previous declaration was just below the bit you posted ("note: previous declaration ..."), assuming you use `g++`.

Comment: @Wintermute You are right. It was a function. the problem was that room was used in a different library. That was why I could not find it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For getting the compiler to show me the type of something, I usually use an improptu class like this:

```
template <class T>
struct show_type;
```

Then, in the code where you need to learn a type, you'd do this:

```
show_type<decltype(room)> t;
```

Compile this, and the compiler will rightfully complain that `show_type<T>` is not defined; but the error message will helpfully spell out the `T` with which the instantiation was attempted.

Comment: Why bother defining `show_type` and using `::type` at all? `template <class T> struct show_type; show_type<decltype(room)> t;`

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized the variable room is `double` which is still confusing to me. do you have any idea about finding its original location?

Comment: @barej Not from the compiler, but most IDEs have a "Go to definition" feature.

Comment: @barej Or, now that you know the type, even a regex such as `double *room` might find something.

Comment: @T.C. You're right, updated. I was under the impression there were some problems with the shortened form, but I can't seem to reproduce them now.

Comment: I do the same thing but I name it `typeof` or `type_of` :)

Answer (score 8):

This can be done easily by declaring a class template and leaving it unimplemented.

```
template<typename T>
struct dump;

dump<decltype(room)> d;
```

This will produce the following error messages on gcc and clang respectively

```
error: aggregate 'dump<CRoom> d' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'dump<CRoom>'
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01c75714f2132725)

An alternative, that allows the program to compile, is to use [Boost.TypeIndex](http://beta.boost.org/doc/html/boost_typeindex_header_reference.html#header.boost.type_index_hpp)

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

std::cout << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(room)>().pretty_name() << '\n';
```

This produces the output `CRoom` on both gcc and clang

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0490c862504a891d)